# Print the matched words which occurred multiple times

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string where I need to fetch the node names from them.

Here is the script which I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "Result data [[The Incident result is shown with Node and IP address. error.log warning.log http://10.0.0.11/home/node_data/2020-07-08_data.txt NODE IP NODE1 10.0.0.1 NODE2 10.0.0.2 NODE3 10.0.0.3 NODE4 10.0.0.4 NODE5 10.0.0.5 ]]";

if($string =~ /(?:(\w+)\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))/){
    #how do I print only the node names. 
    #Here it should print - NODE1,NODE2,NODE3,NODE4,NODE5
} else {
    print "No matching found.\n";
}
```

The above code is able to match the nodes from `$strings`.

But how do I print them or store them in an array.
From above example it should print:

```
NODE1,NODE2,NODE3,NODE4,NODE5
```

Comment: Please try [**`(\w+)\s(?:(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})`**](https://regex101.com/r/RisQRK/1). `$1` fetches you all the nodes.

Comment: You can simply use `\w+(?=\s+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})` or `\w+(?=\s+(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})` (no need for a group)

Comment: @Mandy8055 It prints `NODE1` in `$1`

Comment: Please check [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/RisQRK/2) one.

Comment: Please see the code [**snippet**](https://onlinegdb.com/SkWQ3AVyv) here. Please do let me know if it helped.

Comment: @Mandy8055 it works fine. But there is a `,` at the end. I think I need to remove using `chop`.